# Node.js Mongoose, find document and save if not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just started working with Mongoose, but there is something I just don't understand. I've searched on Stack Overflow and searched the web for the error, but didn't find the proper answer.

**Find, save if document doesn't exist** 
I'm creating a function where the user can add multiple questions. These questions are stored as objects in an array. Like this:

```
const questions = [
  {
    global_id: 'id',
    question: 'question',
    type: 'multipleChoice',
    answers: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
    // more data
  }, 
  // more instances
];
```

**This is the model**

```
/* Mongoose model for Global Questions */
const GlobalQuestionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  global_id: String,
  number: Number,
  connected_playwalls: Array,
  created_by: String,
  created_at: Date,
  question: String,
  type: String,
  total_answers: Number,
  answers: Array,
  valid: Number,
  answer_count: Array,
  average_duration: Number,
  images: Array,
  check: Boolean
});

const GlobalQuestion = module.exports = mongoose.model('GlobalQuestion', GlobalQuestionSchema);
```

When the user posts the data, I first want to loop trough all instances in the array, and use the Mongoose find function to see if there is already a document with the same question and question type. This is how I do it:

```
const save = {
  questionsTest(questions, req) { // questions is the array as above
    questions.forEach(function(question) {
      GlobalQuestion.checkIfExists(question, (err, data) => { 
         if(err) { console.log(err); };
          if(data != null) { // data is a single question object
            GlobalQuestion.createNew(data, (err, result) => {
               if(err) { console.log(err); };
               console.log(result);
           });
          }
       });
    })
}
```

**This is the GlobalQuestion.checkIfExists function**

```
module.exports.checkIfExists = function(data, callback) {
  GlobalQuestion.findOne({
    question: data.question,
    type: data.type
  }, function(error, result) {
      if(error) { console.log(error); }
      console.log(result); // Return nulls now, the document doesn't exist yet          
      if(result == null) {
        callback(error, data);
      } else {
        callback('Question already exists', true);
      }
  });
};
```

**This is the GlobalQuestion.createNew function**

```
module.exports.createNew = function(data, callback) {
  let question = new GlobalQuestion(data);
  question.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
  });
}
```

In the callback of the `GlobalQuestion.checkIfExists` a object is returned in the result. This object contains one single question. The `createNew` function creates a document for first question, but after that I get this error:

```
BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error index: playwall-test-server.globalquestions.$id_1 dup key: { : null }
```

The weird thing is, is that the question object doesn't have `id` key, but a `global_id` key. I've been debugging a lot now, but I just can't find the solution.

What am I doing wrong here? So my goal is to loop trough an array of objects and check for each object if it exists as document (based on question & question type). If not, I want to create a new document.

Comment: add your model too

Comment: @VictorOliveira done!

Comment: do you have a unique key defined somewhere?

Comment: No, the `global_id` is unique (generated with npm uniqid package), but not declared as unique in the schema

Comment: I believe the problem is related with your questions declarations. questions['normal'] = ...
Try removing this ['normal'] and say what happens

Comment: @VictorOliveira `const questions` is now the array with objects. Still the same error. In the `questions.forEach(function(question) { })`, the  `question` variable is a single object

Comment: I see. Mongoose creates a unique _id key for each data it saves automatically. What may be causing the problem is that you are returning null when finding nothing. And then you execute a 

new GlobalQuestion(data); where data is null.

I believe because of that you are always trying to create the same null object. Can you print what your schema looks like now? I believe should be something like _id: null

Comment: @VictorOliveira this is the response that I get when logging the data in `GlobalQuestion.createNew()`:

```{ global_id: 'test0',
  question: 'Test',
  type: 'multipleChoice',
  answers: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ],
  _id: 5aad5e1269e742d39d20da65 }```

The other one is like that as well (with a different `_id`, but there is no `null` object in the create function.

Comment: this is one question, can you print all of them? You just need to do find({}) and the response will be all questions saved

Comment: You shouldn't mix synchronous forEach with asynchronous Mongoose operations. It leads to unexpected results + you'll never know when all the async operations are done. Use promises or [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries).

Comment: I can't print all questions here (to less characters available in reactions). But it prints just one saved document. I saved two, so just one is added. If i print `let question` inside the `createNew() ` it doesnt return null once, but two question objects with both an different `_id` key

Comment: The problem was an index that was set in MLab. I deleted the id key there, and recreated the functions. Now I also did it with an async. approach. Thanks for your help!